# Android WebView isn't displaying Tables correctly

Tags: android, html, webview

What I have is a simple WebView app to display a website. The issue is when I run the app on API 16 that the WebView doesn't display a table correctly all of the time. If I restart the app a few times, it will eventually load fine. Seemingly random though, it will do some crazy things to the table. I've also ran this app on API 19, 20, and 21 without ever having this issue.

**When it loads fine:**

[image]

**And when it doesn't**

[image]

Below are my snippets of code from the project. I should also note that I have the basics like internet permissions in the manifest and javascript enabled before loadUrl.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</WebView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.mywebsite.com/page.html");

}
```

**HTML loading in WebView**

```
<div style="z-index: 5001; position: fixed; width: 100%; top: 0px; background-color: white;">
<table style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="border: 1px solid silver;" id="menu1-t" ><img style="width: 100%; max-width: 60px;" src="images/image.png" ></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid silver;" id="menu2-t" ><img style="width: 100%; max-width: 60px;" src="images/image.png" ></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid silver;" id="menu3-t" ><img style="width: 100%; max-width: 60px;" src="images/image.png" ></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid silver;" id="menu4-t" ><img style="width: 100%; max-width: 60px;" src="images/image.png" ></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid silver;" id="menu5-t" ><img style="width: 100%; max-width: 60px;" src="images/image.png" ></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid silver;" id="menu6-t" ><img style="width: 100%; max-width: 60px;" src="images/image.png" ></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

If anybody has seen this before or has any ideas, help would be much appreciated.

Comment: on android 4.4 (or is it 4.3?) you can debug the webview using chrome on your computer.

Comment: @njzk2 It's actually Android 4.1.2... are there webview debug options for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems simply adding `table-layout: fixed` and  `box-sizing: border-box` to my table has solved the problem.